# "hand made" or "handmade" what is formally correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I also have a question about using this word: "Katarina Handmade" or "Handmade by Katarina" is the meaning different? What is correct?

Comment: It's *handmade*. You can look this up in [many dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=handmade&ls=a&loc=home_ac_Hand+made). Even if you look up *hand made* in most dictionaries, they will redirect you to *handmade*. As to your other question, the second one is much better. Other people here can provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that we should use "handmade" as a compound word (i.e. no spaces):

> Handmade

[Source 1](http://thefreedictionary.com/handmade) [Source 2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handmade)

Personally, I would instinctively write this as one single word.

We can then say,

> Handmade by Katarina

but we could also say

> Katarina's handmade products

But not

> Katarina handmade

Comment: OK, in this case is "Katarina" as a private person. What if I am talking about Katarina as a company name, I mean a brand. Is it different?

Comment: No. Well, I mean it's a name so you've got artistic license, but I don't think it sounds great to say "Katarina Handmade".

Answer (score 1):

The difference I get from it by saying them aloud is Katarina Handmade sounds like it's produced or crafted by the company as a whole as opposed to it being made by the individual.  Even though we all know 'Katarina' isn't usually making the product but the staff of empoyee(s) are.  That being said, we still like knowing a product is handmade and, even if it isn't, just hearing or reading that it is still leaves a good mark in our subconscious.